# coc.nvim autocompletion for threejs

Tags: three.js, autocomplete, neovim, coc.nvim

i want autocompletions for [three.js](https://threejs.org) in nvim , kind of like the autocompletions we get if we open three.js file on a split window on vim [still not good], i searched in coc language plugins list, i cant find a plugin which satisfy my needs.
like,
[image: document autocompletion]
:spl path/to/three.js 
^W ↓
i
[image: three js autocompletion]
this is just recommending random words from the file on the other window,
but what i need is sord of like,

```
THREE.|
      [Scene]
      [PerspectiveCamera]
      [WebGLRenderer]
      [Mesh]
```

Comment: I believe this question belongs [in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vim), since it's targeted to a specific text editor, not to programming or Three.js in general. You should also consider visiting the Neovim forum for help from people who focus on that specific software: https://neovim.discourse.group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `"suggest.defaultSortMethod": "none"` in your coc-settings.json, this will use the order from language server, here is tsserver.